# 'libxml/xmlwriter.h' not found after updating to Xcode 7.0.1 and El Capitan

Tags: xml, xcode7, osx-elcapitan, ns-3

I just updated my MacBook to *El Capitan* and I have now *Xcode 7.0.1*. When compiling my NS-3 script, I get the following error (I didn't have before the update):

```
 In file included from ../src/config-store/model/config-store.cc:11:
    ../src/config-store/model/xml-config.h:5:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlwriter.h' file not found
    #include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>
             ^
    1 error generated.
    Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/marcogiordani/final-ns3-mmwave-dir/build'
    Build failed
     -> task in 'ns3-config-store' failed (exit status 1): 
        {task 4469735696: cxx config-store.cc -> config-store.cc.1.o}
    ['/usr/bin/g++', '-Wall', '-Werror', '-Wno-potentially-evaluated-expression', '-Wno-unused-local-typedefs', '-fPIC', '-I.', '-I..', '-I/usr/include/libxml2', '-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE', '-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE', '-DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1', '-DHAVE_IF_NETS_H=1', '-DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H=1', '-DHAVE_SQLITE3=1', '../src/config-store/model/config-store.cc', '-c', '-o', 'src/config-store/model/config-store.cc.1.o']
```

Any suggestion to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To whom it may concern, I have just solved the problem by typing on the Terminal:

```
xcode-select —-install
```

For some reason, when updating to Xcode 7.0.1, the CommandLineTool hadn’t been updated too, so I did it manually. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

update on this with macOS Mojave: I still had the problem after installing both CLI tools with `xcode-select --install` and libxml2 / libxslt with brew.
The only thing that fixed the problem was installing missing legacy headers as pointed out here: https://silvae86.github.io/sysadmin/mac/osx/mojave/beta/libxml2/2018/07/05/fixing-missing-headers-for-homebrew-in-mac-osx-mojave.html

Simply run 
`sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`
and there you go!